# How to get the last object of an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

So I have an array which the amount of items could vary. I was wondering if there is anyway I can get the last object of an `NSArray`? I did think of having like an `int` counter to trace the amount of items in the array however that seems too much of a hassle.

Does anyone know anyway that's better than this?

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to use `[Array lastObject]`, you can also do `[NSArray objectAtIndex:[Array count]-1];`, but the other methods are cleaner.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Expanding a bit on the question, there are several situations in which one could need the last object of an array, with different ways to obtain it.

### In a straight Cocoa program

If one just wants to get the object in course of a standard Cocoa program, then this will do it:

```
[myArray lastObject]
```

To address the concern of the counter - no need to implement one's own, either:

```
NSUInteger myCount = [myArray count];
```

### Using key-value coding (KVC)

In case one needs to access the last object of an array through KVC, the story requires a bit of explanation.

First, requesting the value of a normal key from an array *will create a new array consisting of the values of that key for each of the objects in the array*. In other words, a request for the key `lastObject` from an array will make the array send `valueForKey:` to each of the objects using the key `lastObject` on them. Apart from not being the intended result, it will also likely throw an exception.

So in case one really needs to send a key to the array itself (as opposed to its contents), the key needs to be prepended with an `@`-sign. This tells the array that the key is intended for the array itself, and not its contents.

The key therefore has to have the form `@lastObject`, and be used like this:

```
NSArray *arr = @[@1, @2, @3];

NSNumber *number = [arr valueForKey: @"@lastObject"];
```

### In a sort descriptor

An example of how this key could be used in a real program is a situation where an array of arrays needs to be sorted by the *last* object in each of the inner arrays.

The above key is simply used in the sort descriptor:

```
NSArray *arrayOfArrays = @[@[@5, @7, @8], @[@2, @3, @4, @6], @[@2, @5]];

NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"@lastObject" ascending: YES];

NSArray *sorted = [arrayOfArrays sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[sd]];
```

### In a predicate

Likewise, in order to filter an array of arrays, the key can be used directly in a predicate:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"self.@lastObject > 5"];

NSArray *filtered = [arrayOfArrays filteredArrayUsingPredicate: pred];
```

People preferring to leave the `self`-part out can simply use the format `@"@lastObject > 5"`

Comment: How did I not see that…  Thanks. Since you answered first I'll mark you as the correct one

Comment: Returns nil if the array is empty.

Answer (score 18):

```
[yourArray lastObject];
```

see the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Answer (score 10):

Maybe like this:

```
id object = [myArray lastObject];
```

A good tip is to option-click on any symbol you want to read documentation for. For example hold down the option key and click on any text that says `NSArray` in your Xcode editor.

You get a nice popup with the basics, and a link for full detailed documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Or if you want to get fancy:

```
yourArray.lastObject
```

Comment: `lastObject` is not a property. dot-notation is for properties. I dont know why the compiler allows this though.

Comment: @vikingosegundo The dot notation is just sugar coating for calling a method. So while calling any method using the dot notation is valid, it is considered bad practice.

Comment: @qegal It's possible to call a method with the dot notation that doesn't take any parameters, try it out.