# How to get last array values from NsmutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the last object of an NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175256/how-to-get-the-last-object-of-an-nsarray)

In my iPhone application, I want to retrieve the last array value from `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:messages];
NSLog(@"array : %@", array);
```

In this "array". I having this below values.

```
hi, hello,
```

I want to take `hello` values only from the `NSMutableArray`.

How can I do this?

Comment: We can understand spelling/case mistakes in question body. But your code is full of errors.. Why can't you copy/paste the code from xcode?

Comment: @Gopi : you should accept the answer and vote up/down accordingly, otherwise no one will take interest of doing thing for you... :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NSLog(@"array : %@",[array lastObject]);
```

It may help's you

Answer (score 0):

you should follow indexpath at `[array count] - 1` to obtain the last value.

For Ex,

```
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@",[array objectAtIndex:[array count] - 1]];
   NSLog("last object of an array = %@",str);
```

Enjoy Programming!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
NSString *str = (NSString *)[array lastObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[array lastObject]` returns the last object of the array.

```
NSArray *arr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
NSString *last=[arr lastObject];
NSLog(@"Last obj in string : %@",last);
```

Output :

```
Last obj in string : C
```