# How to find array last element

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray * arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",...@"n" ,nil];
```

how to get last position of this array

Any help really appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to google ?

Comment: By googling you don't risk your life!

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175256/how-to-get-the-last-object-of-an-nsarray

Comment: Congratulations.  That's probably the record number of downvotes in an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last object:

```
[arr lastObject];
```

and to get the position of last object:

```
[arr count] - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You get last object of array like this:

```
[arr lastObject]
```

Number of items in array:

```
[arr count]
```

Answer (score 0):

Index of last element :

```
int index = [arr count] - 1;
```

Last element :

```
[arr lastObject];
```