# How to get last array object as int

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, object, int

How can I get the last object from an array as an int, for example if I have 20 objects in the array, how can I get the last object as an int variable that = 20. Or if the array had 999 objects, the last object int would = 999.

How can I do this? I have tried using `(int)array.lastobject` but have had no luck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what type of objects are you storing in the array?

Comment: Try grabbing the element at the `length - 1` th index!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the last object of an NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175256/how-to-get-the-last-object-of-an-nsarray)

Comment: From the post,it seems that you want `array.count`.

Comment: I am storing strings in the array

Comment: You want last object or array count??

Comment: @CoolKatStudios Tell the reason why you accepted Amit Answer because   Asif Mujteba Given answer first and it is correct. so don't to like this okk.

Comment: @CoolKatStudios You have not replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use lastObject method  to get last object from array

```
 int lastValue = [[yourArray lastObject] intValue];
```

Comment: Just curious, How is this different from my answer? which was submitted 8 mins earlier?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what type of objects are being stored in the array? if they are `NSNumber` or `NSString` than you can do this:

```
int myVar = [[array lastObject] intValue];
```

**Edit:**
Your question is rather confusing it also seems that you want array count instead of last object? If thats the case than use this:

```
int myVar = [array count];
```

Comment: reason for down voting please ??

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

```
int yourVariable = [[yourArray lastObject] intValue];
```

### Option 2

```
int yourVariable = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:([yourArray count]-1)] intValue];
```

Comment: Just curious, how is this different from my answer? as OP just wants to know how to get int from last object?

Comment: @AsifMujteba : Its not about how this is different... By d way I posted two options...

Comment: Option 2 is not a good option.If youtArray.count is 0,this will crash.lastObject is way more better